# Parse jenkins rest API

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, jenkins

I am using Jenkins xml api with tree. Here is the url I am using for my locally hosted Jenkins server.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/xml?
   tree=jobs[name,description,color,healthReport[score,description]]
```

The above url shows me xml output as:

```
<hudson>
    <job>
        <description/>
        <name>build1</name>
        <color>disabled</color>
        <healthReport>
            <description>Build stability: 2 out of the last 5 builds failed.</description>
            <score>60</score>
        </healthReport>
    </job>
    <job>
        <description>test job description check.</description>
        <name>Build2</name>
        <color>blue</color>
        <healthReport>
            <description>Build stability: No recent builds failed.</description>
            <score>100</score>
        </healthReport>
    </job>
    <job>
        <description/>
        <name>Build3</name>
        <color>blue</color>
        <healthReport>
            <description>Build stability: 3 out of the last 4 builds failed.</description>
            <score>25</score>
        </healthReport>
    </job>
 </hudson>
```

Now I would like to parse the xml output in such a way that further I can process the tag values.

ex:

```
foreach job
if color=blue
print jobname : color 
if score = 100
etc
```

How could I do this in perl, which perl module should I use?

Comment: XML::Twig( http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.42/Twig.pm ) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Maverick, I am new to Perl, Perl modules, could you please show me the way, how could i get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with:

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml);
my $root = $doc->documentElement();
```

- foreach job

  ```
  for my $job ($root->findnodes('job'))
  ```
- if color=blu

  ```
  my $color = $job->findvalue('color/text()');
  ```
- print jobname : color

  ```
  my $job_name = $job->findvalue('name/text()');
  ```
- if score = 100

  ```
  my $score = $job->findvalue('healthReport/score/text()');
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure if `/text()` is needed. It might happen implicitly.

Comment: Hi Ikegami,
I tried to implement the logic that you provided into the code.
Seems like its not working.
I am getting this error:
`Can't locate object method "findvalue" via package "XML::LibXML::NodeList" at testperl.pl line 36.`

Comment: XML::LibXML::NodeList? You did something different than directed. `$job` doesn't contain a job element node.

Comment: Hi Ikegami,
The code is working now.
The XML::LibXML is picking the xml file from the folder.
I want to parse the URL(with xml content). I googled it but I havn't get any solution on it.
Is there any way to parse url With XML::LibXML?

Comment: No, you want to parse the document identified by an URL. You need to fetch that document first (using LWP or some such), then parse it as I showed. (`->parse_string($response->decoded_content( charset => 'none' ))`)

Comment: Yep! Printing as expected...Thanks a lot ikegami

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am getting after fetching the web document by LWP::UserAgent.

```
XML::LibXML->load: specify location, string, or IO at 12.pl line 23
```

Though I am passing an url Content to parse, I am getting the above error.

Here is my Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use XML::LibXML;
my $url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,description,color,healthReport[score,description]]';
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;
my $response = $ua->get($url);

if ($response->is_success) {
        my $content = $response->decoded_content;
        #print $response->decoded_content;
        my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
        my $xmldoc = $parser->load_xml($response->decoded_content);
        for my $job ($xmldoc->findnodes('/hudson/job')) {
                my $color = $job->findvalue('color/text()');
                print $color;
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) That should be `$parser->parse_string($xml)` like I showed you, or `XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml)`. 2) That should be `$response->decoded_content( charset => 'none' )` to make sure LWP doesn't mangle the XML. (It can!)

Answer (score 0):

[XML::Hash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3A%3AHash) is another fine option for converting an XML string into a perl hash.

```
# Conversion from a XML String to a Hash
my $xml_converter = XML::Hash->new();
my $xml_hash = $xml_converter->fromXMLStringtoHash($xml);
```